# Get ID of the user that has a crash using Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I want to be able to send a message to a user that has experienced a crash on Firebase Crashlytics. I've read the documentation, the code that I've found is the following:

```
exports.postOnNewIssue = functions.crashlytics.issue().onNew(async (issue) => {
  const issueId = issue.issueId;
  const issueTitle = issue.issueTitle;
  const appName = issue.appInfo.appName;
  const appPlatform = issue.appInfo.appPlatform;
  const latestAppVersion = issue.appInfo.latestAppVersion;

  const slackMessage = `<!here|here> There is a new issue - ${issueTitle} (${issueId}) ` +
      `in ${appName}, version ${latestAppVersion} on ${appPlatform}`;

  await notifySlack(slackMessage);
  console.log(`Posted new issue ${issueId} successfully to Slack`);
});
```

However, I don't see a way to get the ID of the corresponding user that has experienced a crash. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#set_user_identifiers) to attach a user ID, that information isn't delivered in the [Issue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.crashlytics.Issue) object that gets passed to your function.  So, it seems not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Doug! I wanted to do that because I thought it was a good way to apologize to the user